# What's the difference between in/to?

Tags: prepositions, grammaticality

I am confused now because I don't know what is the difference between in/to in the sentence like this one.

For example : She has been *to* York. (And) She has been *in* York.

She was *in* London (and) She was *to* London.
What is the difference between them, do they have different meanings?

Answer (score 14):

This is quite an interesting question because it makes us think of the various meanings of *be*. And what guides us in understanding what meaning *be* takes, is what preposition is used.

**In** indicates a position inside one area.
**To** indicates a movement, you go from one area to another area.

> She has been to York.

indicates **a movement** from a point outside the City of York to the City of York (whatever point in the city).

> She has been in York.

indicates that she was inside the area called "York". It does not suggest a movement.

- **She has been to York** means that at one point in her life she went to York, the main idea of the sentence is in the **trip to York**.
- **She has been in York** means that at one time in her life - it could be a very long time, she was in York **she stayed there**, it says nothing about taking  a trip to York.

This difference in meaning of the verb *be* does not exist in all tenses, we have seen it exists in the present perfect but it does not exist in the past, in the past *be* can only have the meaning of "staying" in one place.

- "She was in London" is correct.
- <strike>"She was to London"</strike> is impossible.

From that point we could ask if when in the present perfect *be* is synonym of *go*, since *go* also indicates a movement from one place to another?
The answer is no. In the present perfect "she has been" and "she has gone" have different meanings.

- > She has been to York.

  means at one point in her life she travelled to York (and as a consequence she now knows this city). When I say these words "she" might very well be standing next to me thousands of miles away from York.
- > She has gone to York.

  means she is not with me when I say these words because she has travelled to York is she is in York at he moment.

Comment: C'est tellement vrai.

Comment: @User26328 Coucou. Actually that's such a tricky point of the English Language that it's difficult to make an answer both up to the point and simple enough to a learner of the language. Deserves an academic paper.

Comment: This is a good answer, made tough by the context of a city.  A different example would have been simple to explain.  Try a lake.  Going to the lake gives you a nice view.  Going in the lake gets you wet.

Comment: @fixer1234 I understood the question to be specific about the use of *in* and *to* with *be*.  I expect OP would understand the use of *in* and *to* with go...